# When weakly compactness implies compactness?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a Banach space. The weak topology on $A$ is a topology which produced by the following family of seminorms:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~P_f(x)=|f(x)|,\qquad$   where $f\in A^*$ and $A^*$ is dual of $A$.

Please itroduce some conditions under them, weakly compact sets are necessarily compact under original topology( norm-topology of Banach space).

Comment: Note that, if a subset $K \subset A$ is norm compact, then the weak topology and norm topology on $A$ are the same. So, you might look for conditions on $A$ which guarantee its weak topology and norm topology coincide.

Comment: @MikeF It is proven that, the weak topology and the strong topology on $A$  coincide if and only if $A$ is finite dimensional. So we suppose that $A$ is not finite dimensional and we ask this question again. I mean, is there a condition under that a weakly compact subset of $A$ (where $A$ is infinite dimensional) is necessarily strongly compact?

Comment: @David: Sorry there are typos in my comment above. I meant to point out that, if $K \subset A$ is norm compact, then the norm topology and weak topology **of** $\mathbf{K}$ are the same. That is, I had meant to talk about relative topologies on the set $K$. As you say, the weak and norm topologies are only the same on $A$ if $A$ is finite dimensional. But, even if $A$ is not finite dimensional, so the weak and norm topologies of $A$ differ, the relative topologies they induce on a subset can coincide.

Comment: Do you say::::
If $A$ is not finite dimensional, and $K$ is a weakly compact subset of $A$, then the norm topology coincides with the weak topology on $K$ ???

Comment: I'm saying it's possible for them to coincide. For example, let $A = \ell^2$ and $K = \{0\} \subset A$. The norm topology and weak topology on $A$ are different, but the relative topologies they induce on the one point set $K$ are the same.